# Setting up MediaController

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

Im trying to set up the MediaController so I can have controls when playing back audio but when I try to declare it the "this" is coming up as an error. What am I doing wrong?

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

```
private boolean cont;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private String OUTPUT_FILE;
private MediaController mediaController;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/androidaudio1.3gpp";
    cont=true;


}



public void buttonClicked(View view){


    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.startRec:
            beginRecord();
            break;

        case R.id.stopRec:
            stopRecord();
            break;

        case R.id.startPlay:
            try {
                begginPlaying();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.stopPlay:
                stopPlaying();
            break;


    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void begginPlaying() throws IOException {

    if (mediaPlayer != null)
        mediaPlayer.release();

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);

    mediaController.show();

    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();


}


private void stopPlaying(){

    if (mediaPlayer!= null){

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
    }


@Override
public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();

}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

MediaController requires the context to be passed to the constructor. Without anymore code or knowing where you declared the MediaController, my best guess is that you don't have access to the context in the place where you declared the MediaController. Either pass the context from the activity where you would like to use the MediaController, or put this code in that activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

**EDIT:**

I tried your code, check your imports & ensure you have, `import android.widget.MediaController` & not `import android.media.session.MediaController`.

Comment: Take a look above I edited the post to include the start of the code

Comment: Yes that did work thank you. Can you also help me out on setting the controller too. When I try setMediaPlayer and pass in my player I get an error

Comment: I dont get a chance to run it. Its a critical error and mediaPlayer is outlined in red, It says "setMediaPlayer in MediaController cannot be applied to android.media.MediaPlayer"

Comment: Change your class to implement `MediaPlayerControl` & then change the method call to `mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this)`.

Comment: Ok i got it to run without error but the media controls still dont display. I edited the code in my post.

Comment: @G-J, try this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787) & see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

if you are using in `Activity` then you can pass `this`
if you are using in `Fragment` then use `getActivity() or context`

and to set MediaController 
use this code

```
video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                /*
                 * add media controller
                 */
                mc = new MediaController(YourActivity.this);
                video.setMediaController(mc);
                /*
                 * and set its position on screen
                 */
                mc.setAnchorView(video);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my original post to include the top of my code. From what I understand since I am using in main activity I should be able to pass this?